# std::shared_ptr not working with range for

Tags: c++, for-loop, c++11, shared-ptr

I'm trying to iterate over a temporary object in a range for loop. It looks like the object gets desctucted before the loop begins executing. Is this a standard compliant behaviour? I'm using gcc 4.8.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

struct Test: std::vector<int> {
  Test(): std::vector<int>{1,2,3} {
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
  }

  ~Test() {
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
  }
};

std::shared_ptr<Test> func() {
  return std::shared_ptr<Test>(new Test);
}

int main() {
  for (const auto &obj: *func()) {
    std::cout << obj << '\n';

  }
}
```

The result is as follows:

```
Test::Test()
Test::~Test()
21770300
0
33
0
0
0
3
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Yes**, the behavior is compliant.

Per paragraph 6.5.4/1 of the C++11 Standard:

> For a range-based `for` statement of the form
>
> ```
> for ( for-range-declaration : expression ) statement
> ```
>
> let *range-init* be equivalent to the expression surrounded by parentheses
>
> ```
> ( expression )
> ```
>
> and for a range-based `for` statement of the form
>
> ```
> for ( for-range-declaration : braced-init-list ) statement
> ```
>
> let *range-init* be equivalent to the *braced-init-list*. **In each case, a range-based for statement is equivalent to**
>
> ```
> {
>     auto && __range = range-init;
>     for ( auto __begin = begin-expr,
>         __end = end-expr;
>         __begin != __end;
>         ++__begin ) {
>         for-range-declaration = *__begin;
>         statement
>     }
> }
> ```

In your case, the returned shared pointer is dereferenced, and the object it points to is bound to the `__range` reference. However, the shared pointer itself is not copied, nor is it bound to a reference that would prolong its lifetime. Therefore, it goes out of scope. Being the last shared pointer referencing the pointed object, the object gets destroyed too.

Things would have been different if you had returned your `Test` object by value, rather than returning a shared pointer:

```
Test func() {
  return Test();
}

int main() {
  for (const auto &obj: func()) {
    std::cout << obj << '\n';

  }
}
```

This way, the `Test` temporary returned by `func()` is bound to the  `__range` reference, and its lifetime is prolonged to match the lifetime of the reference.

Here is a [**live example**](http://ideone.com/JjvQZT).

Comment: Other than the simple choice to hold the `shared_ptr` instance in local scope, are there any recommended workarounds?